# Connecting Intel Realsense D435 to iPhone with iOS

Tags: ios, realsense

Is it possible to connect the D435 to an iPhone, in a similar manner to the Structure Sensor (see https://structure.io)?

OpenCV is deployable in iOS, but what about Intel Realsense SDK?